# Linking a floating button in tabbed activity to each tab

Tags: android

I have created a tabbed activity and i have a floating button, i want to link the floating button click to each activity so that when you swipe to one activity and you click on the add button, it open an activity different from the one the other tabs will open

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's nothing in the Android framework that can provide that type of functionality out of the box.

I would first make a base class for the tabs activities, with a method that you can call to trigger the action you want

```
public abstract class BaseTabActivity extends Activity {
  public abstract void OnFloatingButtonClicked(View view);
}
```

Then, in your tabbed activity, you could always keep a reference to what the current tab is, such as:

```
private BaseTabActivity mCurrentActivity;
```

Which you would update every time the tab is changed.

Then, in the click listener for your floating action button, you can call the current tab activity's `OnFloatingButtonClicked` method:

```
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
  mCurrentActivity.OnFloatingButtonClicked(v);
});
```

Alternatively, you can make each tab activity instantiate and handle its own floating button, though that will require some more logic in each activity, to show and hide the button when the tab is left.